# Messaging.SingleEmailMessage attachment size limit? 3, 5, 25?

Tags: apex, email

I have been reading and I have found so many different answers that are not consistent, for the question of what is the maximum attachment size in Apex when using

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setFileName('myfilename.json');
efa.setBody(Blob.valueOf(blabla));
mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileattachment[]{efa});
.....
```

what is the actual max limit of the attachment (efa)? 3mb? 5mb? 25mb?

Comment: @NagendraSingh still confusing but yes I didnt find that question before. apparently salesforce says 5MB is the limit, but is not really because it seems that is only 3mb however if you attach 2 attachments of 2mb each doesnt seem to work, is quite confusing, also, it seems that it differs when the email is sent from apex than when is sent from activities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is 5MB, however when you have the actual file converted into Base64 encoded data, the size of a document increases due to nature of Base64 Encoding and hence you see 3 mb limit.

Moreover you'll see for different types of documents you will have different max file size since the encoding will generate different blob sizes.

Comment: +1 but the number of bytes do not change with encoding by different types of documents. Base64 does not apply any compression.

Comment: I meant different documents might have more/less number of characters for which encoding generates more characters, due to which final size might change.